# sending email after update in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

When the callback `:after_update` has been called, you lose all your changes, so the `*_changed?` methods return false.

I need to send an email after an update when one or more attributes were changed. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

How about prepare your email on before_update and save it to an instance variable, and if the update was successful (after_update) send the email?